# Wordpress pages with a custom permalink and a 404 error

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, permalinks

I've a question about a problem which is really annoying.
I build a Wordpress Website and i migrate it into my web server.
My problem is after creating a new page, i can't access it. I have a 404 error.
I have the same problem when i modify the permalink to have a custom URL.

Does anyone knows how to resolve that ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try updating the rewrite rules. Activate and deactivate your theme. If that wont work, try deleting and recreating the page. It happened to me once when I migrated from localhost to live site.

Comment: I've tested that way but it changes nothing. However i found the solution. The problem was from my .htaccess 
I forget to modify my RewriteBase on it.